# Getting com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException when using JsonItemReader with JacksonJsonObjectReader

Tags: jackson, spring-batch

I am facing an issue with spring batch JsonItemReader, getting the above error when trying to read from json file.

JsonItemReader configuration

> ```
> @Autowired
> private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
>
> @StepScope
> @Bean
> public JsonItemReader<CustomerDTO> customerItemReader(){
>     return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<CustomerDTO>()
>             .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(objectMapper,CustomerDTO.class))
>             .resource(new FileSystemResource(customerFilePath))
>             .name("jsonCustomerItemReader")
>             .build();
> }
> ```

DTO

> ```
> @Data
> public class CustomerDTO {
>     private int id;
>     private String firstName;
>     private String lastName;
>     private String gender;
>     private String contactNo;
>     private String country;
>     private String dob;
> }
> ```

Json Sample

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "id": 372,
>     "firstName": "Jessie",
>     "lastName": "Campos",
>     "gender": "female",
>     "contactNo": "(828) 559-3435",
>     "country": "Poland",
>     "dob": "2017-04-03T11:15:53 -08:00"
>   }
> ]
> ```

Stacktrace

As seen here, the error states that the id is not found in the CustomerDTO object. Not sure why I am getting the error.

> org.springframework.batch.item.ParseException: Unable to read next
> JSON object   at
> org.springframework.batch.item.json.JacksonJsonObjectReader.read(JacksonJsonObjectReader.java:90)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonItemReader.doRead(JsonItemReader.java:110)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke()
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.batch.item.json.JsonItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$299546ea.read()
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]    at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:413)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
> ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
> ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]  at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]   at
> jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy93.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]   at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
> ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]  at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:762)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:752)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
> ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar:2.7.4]    at
> com.example.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:11)
> ~[classes/:na] Caused by:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
> Unrecognized field "id" (class com.example.batch.dto.CustomerDTO), not
> marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])  at [Source:
> (sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream); line: 3, column: 14] (through
> reference chain: com.example.batch.dto.CustomerDTO["id"])     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:61)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:1127)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:2023)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1700)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1678)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:320)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:4650)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2831)
> ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]     at
> org.springframework.batch.item.json.JacksonJsonObjectReader.read(JacksonJsonObjectReader.java:87)
> ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.7.jar:4.3.7]    ... 58 common frames
> omitted

**UPDATE (Workaround)**

After a few hours of debugging, It seems that if I don't use lombok @Data annotation and generate the getters and setters its working. Also if I annotate my DTO with @JsonProperty("") its also able to work. Is there a configuration for jackson which I am missing?

Comment: Please share the full stack trace of the error to be able to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, I have updated with the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I was missing annotationProcessorPath for lombok in my maven compiler plugin. After updating it to below was able to use the JacksonJsonObjectReader with @Data annotation from lombok.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<configuration>
    <source>19</source>
    <target>19</target>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct}</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${version.lombok}</version>
        </path>
        <path>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>${version.mapstruct-lombok}</version>
        </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
</configuration>
```